# How can I lower the scale as much as possible?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Using `BigDecimal`, how can I convert `2.00` to `2`, `1.1230` to `1.123` etc?

How can I get `0` from `2.00`, 1 from `1.10000` or 3 from `0.123`? (lowest scale that don't change the value)

Comment: I understand the first line of your question, but the second line doesn't follow. Why would you want to "get `0` from `2.00`"? Or `3` from `0.123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, [`BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29)

I'm not at all sure what you mean about the second part, though.  Do you want the last digit, or something?

Comment: I want lowest possible scale that I can round BigDecimal to. 2.00 rouded to scale 1 is 2.0 (calue the same), to value 0 is 2 (value the same), to value -1 is 0 (value not the same), so my value is 0. 1.10 rouded to value 1 is 1.1 (ok), to value 0 is 1 (not ok).

Comment: can I `stripTrailingZeros` in a way that it doesn't go into negative scale? so 600.0 would become [600,0] instead of [6,-2]?

Comment: I mean, in a pinch, just do `value = value.stripTrailingZeros(); if(value.scale() < 0) value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY);` which is straightforward enough.